# compare data two table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables

```
Table A
id column_a
01 abc
01 abc
02 abc
02 abc
02 abc
03 abc
03 abc
04 abc
```

Table B

```
id column_b
01 abc
02 abc
02 abc
03 abc
04 abc
```

I'd like to compare those two tables above and to get the results in table a but not in table b like:

```
id column_a
01 abc
01 abc
02 abc
03 abc
```

How could i do it in MySQL?

Thanks a lot!

Updated

Comment: Identical rows in tables? Why? Why do you need them?

Comment: Don't the 2 tables have a Primary Key?

Comment: Then don't call them tables. But anyway, why does `01 abc` appears in the result? It's in table `b` as well. Same for `02 abc` and `03 abc`.

Comment: @ypercube I updated my question,please check

Comment: It seems that the answers you got is what you want. Why do you say that `2, up` should be in the result? It's in table `b` as well.

Comment: Please, why did you rollback to edit-1? Please rollback to edit-4 or 5. It was certainly more useful.

Comment: You have made 2 wrongs: Accepted an answer which did not solve your (ill-defined) problem. Then added another identical question.

Comment: @ypercube, the answer does answered my question. the other question is not identical question. did you read the other one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT A.* FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.column_a = B.column_b AND A.id = B.id
WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

Comment: @xxd : Earlier you said this answer is what you are looking for and now you updated question??

Comment: sorry about that, I opened a new question. sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT A.* FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID AND A.column_a=B.column_b
WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```

Regards

Comment: what is difference between your and vearutop answer?

Comment: @Fahim: When Bizapps posted, vearutop had a (slightly) different answer/vesrion.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select a.id,a.column_a
from (select count(*) as a_num, id,column_a 
from table_a group by id having count(*) > 1) as a 
left join (select count(*) as b_num, id from table_b group by id having count(*) > 1) as b 
on a.a_num > b.b_num;
```